# Is there any GUI tools for "git add -p"?

Tags: git, user-interface

When I use "git add -p", I feel so hard and even more when I need edit the patch file.

I thinks a GUI Tools will be better.

Is there any GUI Tools for this work or just for editing .patch file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[git-cola](https://git-cola.github.io/) is pretty good to stage or unstage patches. Look at all the changes, select some lines, press 'S' and those lines are staged for the commit.

[image: Simple but powerful UI]

Comment: The stock `git gui` tool shipped with Git is able to do just that.

Comment: @kostix, I didn't know `git gui` (I had to install it in my system), you can add that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Another good tool is [Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). It will allow you to stage individual hunks/lines easily.

Comment: Source Tree is available for Windows and Mac OS, but not Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Check **Kompare**. It will do the job.

http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/

Comment: URL changed for https://apps.kde.org/kompare/